# Prometheus - how to monitor other docker containers

Tags: docker, prometheus

I want to use **Prometheus** to monitor my **docker** containers. I can run **Prometheus** with **Grafana** but I do not know how to instruct it to monitor other docker containers.
If possible I would like to see some example. For instance I have **Ubuntu** container running on my host as well as **Gentoo** container. How can I tell Prometheus to monitor them, or perhaps to monitor some application(s) running inside?
Thanks in advance for your time and patience with me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use [cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor), which provides container users an understanding of the resource usage and performance characteristics of their running containers.

A [very good article](https://stefanprodan.com/2016/a-monitoring-solution-for-docker-hosts-containers-and-containerized-services/) about setting up **Prometheus** to monitor **Docker** is using this architecture:

[image: cAdvisor with prometheus]

Briefly, the idea is to collect information about containers using **cAdvisor** and put them into **Prometheus** database. **Grafana** will query the **Prometheus** database and render monitoring charts / values.

To collect data from **cAdvisor** to **Prometheus**, you will have to edit a [configuration file](https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom/blob/master/prometheus/prometheus.yml) (`prometheus.yml`):

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'cadvisor'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['cadvisor:8080']
```

When you have some data in **Prometheus**, the you have to use **Grafana** to view it. A (short) example of monitoring `json` queries you could import into **Grafana** is as follow:

Get % of user CPU :

```
  "targets": [
    {
      "expr": "sum(rate(container_cpu_user_seconds_total{image!=\"\"}[1m])) / count(node_cpu{mode=\"system\"}) * 100",
      "interval": "10s",
      "intervalFactor": 1,
      "legendFormat": "",
      "refId": "A",
      "step": 10
    }
  ]
```

Get % of RAM used :

```
  "targets": [
    {
      "expr": "(sum(node_memory_MemTotal) - sum(node_memory_MemFree+node_memory_Buffers+node_memory_Cached) ) / sum(node_memory_MemTotal) * 100",
      "interval": "10s",
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "",
      "refId": "A",
      "step": 20
    }
  ]
```

For complete json data (too long to be posted here), you can clone this repository :

```
git clone https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom
```

And try to import this [**Grafana** json](https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom/blob/master/grafana/docker_containers.json).

I'm currently using this architecture to monitor a `docker swarm mode` cluster in production, and here is the output of the monitoring that you can find in the github repository.

[image: prometheus with grafana]

Comment: Thanks!!! I will check it, try it and let you know. I am looking for something simple but yet powerful enough and believe Prometheus is a good option.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm using this stack (+node exporter / alert manager) in 3 production sites worldwide, i really appreciate the simplicity of just deploying the `collectors` containers (cAdvisor / node exporter) in hosts and see the graph coming up like magic!

Comment: Thankyou for sharing this answer. Helped me in my use-case as well

Comment: So, I've managed to configure as needed. Just I am puzzled and need to figure out how to configure e-mail notifications when some event (alert) is fired - for instance, some docker container goes down for any reason.

Comment: You should ask another question in StackOverflow for this so that anyone can answer you (don't forget to accept this answer if it has been useful).